# Drools and non-Java applications

Tags: drools, rule-engine

Can Drools be used with non-Java applications? Most examples that I've seen are in conjunction with Drools interfacing with Java applications.

EDIT: Looks like http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/droolsjbpm-integration-docs/html_single/ describes the Drools API on techniques on getting information in and out of Drools.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to expose the functionality that you need from Drools via REST or SOAP and interact with it from your application using that. I wouldn't spend time checking the Drools .NET port is old and out of dated. 
A JS implementation is a good idea.. but just for specific cases.. you don't want your whole business rules running on the client side.. (for a web app of course).

HTH

Comment: Thanks, @salaboy - perhaps I should have made it a bit more clearer. How can Drools access the application objects, if the application objects are written in Python - for example. Perhaps you are suggesting to use REST/SOAP to enable Drools to access the non-Java objects and then fire the rules, with the results/outcome being passed along via the REST/SOAP to the external non-Java application. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't have to be Java, but it does have to be a JVM language (I've used Groovy in the past with Drools). Even then, there's nothing to prevent you from calling a REST service, for example, when a rule fires, and interacting with another system that way.

That said, there are other rules engines in other languages. I believe there is a .NET Drools port, and a [Javascript implementation](https://github.com/C2FO/nools).